# Can't install pip due to "ImportError: No module named parse"

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I've been trying to import pip for python 2.7 but it seems that I'm missing parse module. I already have installed easy_install, and I'm trying to install noise-1.1.1 using pip. But pip doesn't want to be installed.

This is what it looks like.

```
c:\Python27>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\__i
nit__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\ext
ension.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\dis
t.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools.command.install import install
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\com
mand\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from setuptools.command import install_scripts
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\setuptools\com
mand\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.
py", line 17, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse
ImportError: No module named parse
```

Comment: You are running what looks like Python 3 code on Python 2. How did you install `distribute`?

Comment: I did, I installed [this distribute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute). I simply used Cmd and the typical "python setup.py install"

Comment: Not sure how you managed to get Python 3 code with that. Try running the [installation instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#distribute-setup-py) instead.

Comment: Do you recommend I unistall python and reinstall it?

Comment: No, just distribute, see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `distribute` installation is incorrect; for some reason the python 2to3 translation has been run on it (which only should happend automatically when installing with Python 3).

The `urllib.parse` library is the Python 3 equivalent of the `urlparse` library used in Python 2.

Your best bet is to remove the mis-installed version (follow the [uninstallation instructions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#uninstallation-instructions)) then run the [`distribute_setup.py` script](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#distribute-setup-py) instead.

Comment: That worked, must have had some weird bug or something when I installed it, thanks. This works!