# Django migration

Tags: python, django, localhost

I have migrated django website from live server to my localhost, i took the backup of posrgresql database and attached to my localhost i have changed the databse connection details in the live_setting.py and also installed the required packages which were already installed on the live server but i am unable to run the website on my localhost when i use manage.py ruserver command i got the following errors.

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x02BB6530>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 266,in validate num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 158, inget_app_errors self._populate()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 67, in_populate self.load_app(app_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 88, in load_app models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module__import__(name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_social_auth3-0.7.20-py2.6.egg\social_auth\models.py", line 8, in <module>'social_auth.db.django_models'))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module__import__(name)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_social_auth3-0.7.20-py2.6.egg\social_auth\db\django_models.py", line 5, in <module>from social_auth.db.base import UserSocialAuthMixin, AssociationMixin, \
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django_social_auth3-0.7.20-py2.6.egg\social_auth\db\base.py", line 7, in <module> from openid.association import Association as OIDAssociation
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\openid\association.py", line 37, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\openid\cryptutil.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\openid\oidutil.py", line 16, in <module> ImportError: No module named parse
```

I am using python 2.6 and django 1.4.3, how can i solve these errors, i am new to python/django development.

Comment: You're running Python 3 code on Python 2, see e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/15011205/1267329

Comment: But in the requirement file of website i see the following details Django==1.4.3
South==0.7.6
PIL==1.1.7
django-articles==2.4.1
django-contact-form==0.3.1
django-social-auth==0.7.20
httplib2==0.7.7
oauth2==1.5.211
python-openid==2.2.5
sorl-thumbnail==11.12 , all i understand from this it is using django 1.4.3 and this version is not compatible with python 3?am i right?

Comment: it may be related to your `distribute` installation (the tool you're using to install stuff), see the other question. I'm not sure which package is causing the issue for you but "no module named parse" is an issue that I've seen before and it happens due code that tries to import from `urllib.parse` when it doesn't exist in your particular Python installation.

Comment: I am using setup.py install command to install different site packages by directly going inside the directory for example if i want to install django-articles 2.4.1, i simply download it from https://pypi.python.org website after extracting i am using the above command.